# Matlab dependency management

Tags: matlab, maven, ivy

I am looking to apply dependency management to a large-scale Matlab project.

This project imports a large number of java libraries, as well as some compiled C++ code, to the extent that some software best practices are now becoming more essential.

Is anyone aware of something along the lines of Maven/Ivy for use with Matlab?

Comment: Related question "MATLAB programming best practices for medium- to large-scale MATLAB Project" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042761/matlab-programming-best-practices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with Matlab, but sounds like your issue is that you're trying to put a large set of binary files under some sort of version control?

If those files are available in Maven Central, you can use my [ant2ivy script](https://github.com/myspotontheweb/ant2ivy) to generate a starting set of **ivy.xml** and **ivysettings.xml** files.

One of the great things about [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) is that it can be run stand-alone as follows:

```
java -jar ivy.jar -retrieve "lib/[artifact].[ext]" -ivy ivy.xml -settings ivysettings.xml
```

This will download the jars and place them into a "lib" directory (Or whatever directory Matlab uses).

Answer (score 0):

matlab isn't really made for large-scale projects. You'll have to come up with your own code to check for all necessary dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple maven based dependency management for matlab projects using jitpack.io and zip as release format.

Sample project - https://github.com/ragavsathish/mmockito

Simple archetype can be found in https://github.com/ragavsathish/matlab-simple-archetype

Please provide your comments on what can be improved further